# Get window-total-width in another font

Tags: window, fonts

`(window-total-width)` returns the number of columns (characters) that fit in the current window (https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Window-Sizes.html). This will take the current font into account. My header line or mode line might have a different font from the text area (window body). How can I get the number of columns (characters) that fit there instead?

Comment: The mode-line fits in a dedicated window ... have you tried measuring that window expressly, e.g., `with-selected-window` ....?

Answer (score 1):

```
(/ (window-pixel-width)
   (window-font-width nil face))
```

will return the current window width for a given face.